Tauri e2e tests, failed to start webdriver. Failed to match capabilities
I'm trying to setup end-to-end tests for Tauri. I've followed the official documentation but when I try to start my tests I get the following error but it's only superficial:
** (pulsar:12894): WARNING **: 06:38:47.744: Disabled hardware acceleration because GTK failed to initialize GL: Unable to create a GL context.

** (pulsar:12894): WARNING **: 06:38:47.751: webkit_settings_set_enable_offline_web_application_cache is deprecated and does nothing.
  1) "before all" hook in "{root}"
  2) "after all" hook in "{root}"

  0 passing (741ms)
  2 failing

  1) "before all" hook in "{root}":
     SessionNotCreatedError: Failed to match capabilities
      at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:521:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:514:13)
      at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:446:28)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

  2) "after all" hook in "{root}":
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quit')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:47:16)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)

The application starts correctly when I launch it manually. But fails without a reason in the selenium test. Any idea what could be wrong or how can I get a more descriptive error?
